# Event Tracking: How To prevent double loading analytics.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, google-analytics

I have an iframe in my webpage. This iframe contains a form with many selects. To reduce loadtime this iframe is loaded after document.ready with jquery. Now I want to track if the button in the form is clicked. Tracking events with Google Analytics in the webpage works, but if want to track events in the form I have to include analytics.js also in the file that is loaded in the iframe.

Problem: iframe event tracking works but analytics.js is loaded twice and every page request will be counted twice.

To solve this problem  I check if analytics.js is already loaded to prevent double loading, but this has to be done with a small timeout. Timeout depends on the available bandwith of every user and isn't fixed for every user. The same applies to document.ready.

Tracking code can't be included within html file because jquery is loaded after document.ready

So how can I track iframe events without double loading analytics.js?

Comment: The GA code will not load the analytics library twice (or at least that's what their debugger says - there seems to be a built-in function to prevent this). Also browsers are good at caching identical files, so I'm not sure how big the impact would be.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have issues with your `analytics.js` file since it loads twice. To answer your question, I'd like to establish a few pointers.

**How Does Google Analytics Collect Data?**

> The data that Google Analytics uses to provide all the information in your reports comes from these sources:

The HTTP request of the users `browser/system` information
`First-party cookies`

Another point is, `document.ready()` prevents the script from actually loading till the whole document has loaded. Hence, I'd advice you to take the following steps. It should work perfectly.

- Place the analytics.js file just before the body closing tag of your html.
  `<script src="analytics.js"></script>
  </body>`
- Remove the `document.ready()` function and put your internal script just before the analytics script tag as well.

This should prevent the double loading and effectively make the script run without reloading.

PS. If it doesn't work, I'd like to see your code. However, it should work perfectly.